# Access spot in .dat file

Tags: java, file, pointers, io, randomaccessfile

Is there any way to move the pointer of a RandomAccessFile to a specific value?
I'm trying to develop a program which will take in five student IDs and their respective GPA, and then access any of the grades from the .dat file based upon the Student ID. The only way I can think of doing this is to have some method that takes an input, and then scans for the appropriate equivalent ID, takes that pointer position and moves it so many spaces (lets say 2 bytes) in order to find the position where it should print.

Below is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * 
 * Pseudocode
 * Welcome user
 * Implement the ReadWrite class
 * First Loop
 *   interactively assign the ID and GPA score
 * Second Loop
 *   When user gives an input ID, return respective GPA

 */
public class U8_Problem3 {

//Main Method
public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Creates a new instance of the file
    File newFile = new File ("Stu.dat");
    try(
        RandomAccessFile newRAFile = new RandomAccessFile(newFile, "rw");
    ){
        //Initialize variables
        int iD = 0;
        double gPA;
        //Collect IDs and GPAs
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the Student ID: ");
            iD = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the GPA: ");
            gPA = input.nextDouble();
            newRAFile.writeInt(iD);
            newRAFile.writeDouble(gPA);
            newRAFile.writeUTF("\n");
        }
        //read back
        while ((iD >= 0)){
            System.out.println("Enter in the ID of the student whose GPA you'd like to view.\n Type a negative number to exit the program.");
            System.out.println("ID: ");
            iD = input.nextInt();
            //This is where I'm stuck

        }
        newRAFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Program complete");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you read the [`RandomAccessFile` Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I couldn't find anything that met the criteria.

Comment: If you enforce a fixed width per record you could simply iterate through until you reach the ID you want. i.e. newRAFile.skipBytes(10).

Another alternative is to keep an index of IDs and their location in the file. Then just lookup the location and do something like newRAFile.seek(location)